# Is it possible to have a h:commandLink (or similar) to navigate to an URI with a fragment?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

For instance, say I want to run some logic and then hit /page.html#elementid

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.action}" value="Go"/>
```

and

```
public String action()
{
   // Some logic here
   return "/page.xhtml#elementid";
}
```

I cannot find any examples regarding this, and wonder if there is a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#elementid` URI fragment has to be sent to the client side as well. This is not happening here. You're basically performing a server-side forward. You should be performing a client-side redirect instead.

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/page.xhtml#elementid");
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could conditionally render some JavaScript to set the URI fragment:

```
public String action() {
    // ...

    hash = "elementid";
    return "/page.xhtml";
}
```

with in `page.xhtml`:

```
<h:outputScript target="body" rendered="#{not empty bean.hash}">
    location.hash = "#{bean.hash}";
</h:outputScript>
```

---

The [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) by the way has explicit support for URI fragments.

```
<h:link value="Go to page" outcome="page" fragment="elementid" />
```

It however fires a GET request, so any preinitializing business actions needs to be performed in the bean associated with the target page based on (post)constructor or `<f:viewParam>`.

Comment: Perfect answer, as always. Thank you.